# Calling a simple Golang executable from PHP failing with exec: "zip": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: php, path, zip, apache2

Trying to execute a simple Golang executable from PHP

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("zip").Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error Executing the command: \n")
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
    } else {
        output := string(out[:])
        fmt.Println("Command Executed successfully with Output \n" + output)
    }

}
```

Here is my php calling script

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$output = shell_exec('zip 2>&1');
echo("Output of Calling zip command from PHP --> ".$output . "<br>");


$output = shell_exec('./genfilesdir/gotest  2>&1');
echo("Output of Calling zip command through golang --> ".$output);

?>
```

Here is the output of the PHP execution

```
Output of Calling zip command from PHP --> adding: -PK-�4PR��������- (deflated 0%) PKPK-�4PR�!-PK/M
Output of Calling zip command through golang --> Error Executing the command: exec: "zip": executable file not found in $PATH
```

When I try to execute the golang from command line, It works

```
> sudo -u www-data ./gotest
Command Executed successfully with Output 
P�4PR��������-PP�4PR�!-PK/M
```

- zip is available in /usr/bin and /usr/bin there in $PATH for www-data
- When I call the 'zip' from PHP directly , It works ( see the php output above)
- I am not sure , why golang executable when called fro PHP not able to pick "zip" in the path.

Here is the environment details

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu 20.04)
PHP 8.0.2 (cli) (built: Feb 14 2021 14:21:37) ( NTS )

What am I missing ?

Comment: I think this is related to your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133115/pass-env-var-to-exec-command

Comment: This one is just an example. I don't have any control on the original go executable i am using. Won't be able to make any changes in go executable. I can do changes in my php code , apache2 or php settings.

Comment: When I switch PHP Version from 8.0 to 7.4 , This works .. So the issue seems to be Php 8.0. How to fix this ?